# how to make sub folder for login page and rest of the pages in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am working in a codeigniter project in wamp server.

My current login page is `http://localhost/flowers/login` and its working correctly (no issue). The rest of the urls are like this
`http://localhost/handycheck/admin/dashboard` etc

My issue is i need to change the login url like this
`http://localhost/flowers/admin/login`
&
`http://localhost/flowers/providers/login`

Its because I have to maintain login form for multiple users.
How can i make this.
Please help me and thanks in advance who helps me alot..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding custom roue in codeigniter routing configuration as follows go to config/routes and add the following entry in this file

```
$route['flowers/providers/login'] = 'flowers/login';
$route['flowers/admin/login'] = 'flowers/login';
```

this will redirect the request to the login in flowers controller and if you need to do custom handling for admins and provider you can get the url segments and do custom handling according to user type

I hope my answer would be useful

Comment: thnx Alaa M for the reply, 
I made the changes in the routes.php
Now i have login.php in controllers/admin folder
but when i try to access http://localhost/flowers/admin/login it redirects to http://localhost/flowers/login.. ? Why ?

Comment: if you need admin to redirected to admin/login just remove the entry $route['flowers/admin'] from route it will return to its default behavior